What would be $q$ in ARIMA(p,d,q) model for the following discrete-time transfer function model?
A general ARIMA(p,d,q) model is given by:$(1-B)^d\phi(B)X_t = \theta(B)a_t$
where p is the order of AR term:$\phi(B)=(1-\phi_1B-\phi_2B^2-\phi_pB^p)$ and d is the order of MA term: $\theta(B)=(1-\theta_1B-\theta_2B^2-\theta_qB^q)$
$(1-B)^d$ represents the differencing term where d is the order of I term and $a_t$ is random white noise.
B is the backward shift operator.
I have the following transfer function between the output at k and the random noise: $$X(k) = 0.2 B \frac{1 }{1-B}a(k)$$
I believe since there is $(1-B)$ in the denominator, $d=1$ in the ARIMA model. But I was confused about the numerator, what would the order of the MA term be? I'm confused because there is no $1+0.2B$ term to say that MA(1). Would $q=1$ even without adding $a(k)$ to the lagged term?
Thank you for reading the question any help is appreciated.

Hi: You can use the results for an infinite geomtric series which is what $\frac{a(k)}{1-B}$ is. It's equal to $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} a(k-i)$. Then you can multiply by the 0.2 B afterwards.

@markleeds thank you for your reply. So in this case the model would be an infinite moving average MA(∞)? what if I want it in terms of ARIMA where I'm considering (1-B) as differencing term (i.e., there is I term d=1)? would it work that way? how would it look like?

maybe we can incorporate the $\frac{.2B}{1-B}$ in one full swoop. Let me work on scrap and see if I can get anywhere with that.

I had it wrong in above. Let me write it out in an answer and get it correct this time. My apologies.

user1156850: I had it wrong again in the answer below so I modified it accordingly. I'm sure that it's correct now. apologies for confusion.

You have the following transfer function:
$$X(k) = 0.2 B \frac{1 }{1-B}a(k)$$
We assume that $k = 1,2,\ldots, n$ and X(1) = 0 ( which implies a(1) = 0 ).
So, we can do this two different ways.
Solution 1: Multiply by $(1-B)$ on both sides which gives
$$X(k) - X(k-1) = 0.2 \times a(k-1)      ~~~~\forall k = 2, \ldots n $$
I think it is okay that there is not an $a(k)$ term because I'm pretty sure that the transfer response is based on past values of $\{a(k)\}$ and not the contemporary value, $a(k)$. I would need to look at a Pankratz or Box-Jenkins to refresh myself.
Anyway.
Solution 2: Divide the Solution 1 by $(1-B)$ on both sides which gives
$$ X(k) = 0.2 \times \sum_{i=0}^{k-2} a(k-1-i) $$
Solution 2 is more intuitive to me compared to Solution 1 because it says that $X(k)$ is a scaled finite sum of all past error terms.
This makes sense when one goes back to Solution 1.
Recall that Solution 1 says that the $\Delta X(k) = 0.2 \times a(k-1)$.
So, assuming $X(1) = 0 $, then this implies that
$\sum_{i=2}^{k} \Delta X(i) = X(k) = 0.2 \times \sum_{i=0}^{k-2} a(k-1-i)$.
So, the algebra above shows that the difference, $X(k) - X(k-1)$, being the previous and scaled error term implies that the non-differenced series, $X(k)$, is the sum of all of previous and scaled error terms ( economists refer to error terms as shocks ).
I hope this helped as far as explaining (albeit vaguely) how the transfer function can be used to see what X(k) really is.
Yes it is an ARIMA(0,1,1) but it's actually the undifferenced series
that has the more interesting dynamics. It's the scaled cumulative sum of all the past error terms,
Note that one can think of things in the opposite direction. The series
(i.e. undifferenced ) is a summation of past error terms and clearly non-stationary. So, if one wants to obtain a stationary series, one needs to difference it. The differencing gets rid of the summing process but summing is what is really going on when one looks under the hood.
